# How to add the U2 album to my iPod?

Tags: icloud

I see the new U2 album in my library. I sync my iPod but the album does not sync. I click the "Add to" arrow in iTunes and select "Add to iPod" but still no luck.

Apple discussions appear to be down.

Anyone got an answer for me? Totally lost here.

Answer (score 2):

*From iPhone/Pod...*

Open 'Music' Click 'Songs'
At the top you then see a link to 'Store'

Once in the iTunes Store click 'More' at the bottom.
Then... Purchased > Music, scroll to U2
Next to Songs of Innocence, click the Cloud icon, it should change to Downloading

*From iTunes...*

Click iTunes Store
Once in the store, click the Home if you're not already there.
To the right, under Quick Links click Purchased, then Not in my Library.

Then same procedure as above, look for the Cloud icon [I already got mine so I can't repeat the steps exactly.]

Comment: here u go, more precious points for a good answer :)